# web api help page is showing base class properties that are hidden by new in the child class

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have some classes like this:

```
public class MyBase
{
   public string name;
   public bool active;
   public List<RequestVersion> Versions;
}

public class MyChild : MyBase
{
   public int Id;
   public DateTime ModifiedDate;
   public new List<ResponseVersion> Versions;
}
```

When the help pages are generated MyChild class shows Versions twice.  Once from the base class and once from itself.  Any ideas on how to get rid of that.  My real classes are more complicated than this, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a separate base class that doesn't contain "Versions", and then inheriting both of these classes from it with their own version of "Versions"